# Can't achieve this: onClick of button, grab the current Page URL and Post to a zapier webhook

Tags: google-tag-manager, zapier

I have a button on a page and a GTM tag that successfully triggers the button is click. I can't seem to figure out the Custom HTML that should happen so when people click the button, it'll grab the Page URL that the button is on and simply post it to a Zapier webhook (from which I can then parse and process).

FYI, the page url is this format:
https://www.example.com/free-report-download/?EM=johndoe%40gmail.com&FN=John&MB=8005555555&cid=d9e8d0ed-fe53-4443-b55e-1c3dcfe4db37

Answer (score 1):

## Update hours later after tinkering

Gave up on using GTM. After using javascript and jQuery, I got the result I wanted!

```
<form id="my-form">
  <input type="hidden" id="location" name="location" value="" />
    <input type="submit" value="Get this Freebie" onclick="window.location.href='https://example.com/subpage'" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[

document.getElementById('location').value = window.location.href;

document.getElementById('my-form').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
});

  //]]></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    (function($){
        function processForm( e ){
            $.ajax({
                url: 'https://hooks.zapier.com/hooks/catch/1234567/xxxxxxx/',
                dataType: 'hidden',
                type: 'post',
                contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function( data, textStatus, jQxhr ){
                    $('#response pre').html( data );
                    console.log(data)
                },
                error: function( jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown ){
                    console.log( errorThrown );
                }
            });

            e.preventDefault();
        }

        $('#my-form').submit( processForm );
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

Now if there's an easier way to do this, let me know.